# Codeblocks - upload binary to server after compilation

Tags: ssh, scp, ide

I'm running Debian 7.6 on VirtualBox and I also have a Debian VPS.
Is there any way to setup Code::blocks to automatically scp the binary after compilation to my VPS?

Answer (score 0):

After trying different things, it looks like I found the answer:
Project > build options > pre/post build steps.

You can use the pre and post steps to execute commands and scripts, so I put the following command in the post step:

> sshpass -p "my_password" scp /path/to/binary/file
>   user@example.com:/path/to/remote/directory

This will execute this line every time after compilation. So, in this case, it'll scp the binary file to the server every time after compiling.
The sshpass part ensures that the password is applied to the scp command.

Seems to work for me :)